# Adding language option in one component but not captions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

I need to provide a language option (en/de) in just *one* of my components, currently for the **captions** in my app we use i18n and it works great, but this it content not captions. I am also aware of the option of lazy loading languages, the thing is that here I want the captions to **remain** in English but the content to have the option to be in German. What might be a good approach to achieving this?
To be clear, the German content will only be loaded later and it is only relevant for a single component and not the entire app, it also does not apply to captions.

Answer (score 0):

With vue-i18n, you can provide a locale explicitly in your component in german:

https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#vue-injected-methods

```
$t('yourKey', 'de')
```

It also works with the directive: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#v-t

You can load both languages, set english as the default language, and explicitly use german in your special component.